# Verify C2DM Auth Token - Android / Urban Airship

Tags: android, android-c2dm, urbanairship.com

I'm (attempting) to use push notifications with Android via Urban Airship.

I've register for C2DM, and received the confirmation email, generated my auth token - but when I try to send a test push notification I get this error:

```
C2DM push to apid ***ID number here*** failed due to invalid auth token
```

How can I verify that the auth token is correct?

Comment: After much head scratching I finally got pushes to work using a bash script from the folks over at Urban Airship - http://pastebin.com/bQF7EksJ . This resolved my auth problem, but not my UA problem. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the authentication token being included in the headers of the POST? The only reasons I can think of are that the authentication token wasn't sent or is old.

Comment: I'm sending the push from the Urban Airship control panel - I'm assuming the token is passed on.

Comment: http://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/articles/search?q=auth+token Maybe this will help you. I recommend seeking out personal help with urbanairship.com if none of those topics fix the problem.

Comment: No problem. May I ask what solved the problem so that future viewers can see?

Comment: It's unresolved as of now - I've just marked correct the suggestion to pursue this over on UA. Will post an answer here when I have one. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the reason is case sensitive auth-header, see:
[c2dm 401 error when sending messages after receiving id and auth token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7639678/c2dm-401-error-when-sending-messages-after-receiving-id-and-auth-token/7771710#7771710)

Hope that helps,
regards CL