# GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) Bulk with Linux

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

Does any one have idea about the best way(implantation) to send Bulk Google Cloud Messaging on a Linux server. (Personally I like non-java implementation) Any help, link or suggession appreciated.

**Edit**

I didn't try any method for bulk messaging. I know there is a php implementation for GCM too, But I like to know what should I consider before go for an implementation. Like, How to handle failed messages, Is there any limitation on http requests goes to GCM server, etc.

Comment: I didn't try any method for bulk messaging. I have implemented php+mysql+ cron job for APNS. I know there is a php implementation for GCM too, But I like to know what should i consider before go for an implementation. Like, How to handle failed messages, Is there any limitation on http requests goes to GCM server, etc.

Comment: Explanation for down votes might help me to improve my self, Be kind enough to give a brief explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found the best answer for my own question. We can send a message to 1000 Google could message recipients using one `http` request. Sending bulk messaging Shouldn't be that much complicated. Any language or tool are capable of sending appropriate `http` request to the GCM server is enough.

> GCM allows you to attach up to 1,000 recipients to a single message,
>   letting you easily contact large user bases quickly when appropriate,
>   while minimizing the work load on your server.

Answer (score 2):

As shown by [this example](http://labs.distriqt.com/post/1223), it seems that the server-side code can even be written in `C#`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12417704/how-to-implement-push-notifications-in-android) also confirms that this approach works. Other people seems to be able to setup standalone Java applications, as [shown here](http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Google-Cloud-Messaging-How-create-86481.S.139378077).

If you have to setup a Linux server to send `GCM` push notifications, you can freely chose to use `C#` or `Java` at your own discretion.

For what concerns `C/C++`, however, things are a little more complicated. [This question (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396177/gcm-sending-with-curl-php) shows that `GCM` notifications can be sent using `CURL`, so I suspect that a "C/C++" implementation using `libCurl` could be possible. However you'll have to tweak it yourself, given that it does not seem to be the "standard way" to use `GCM`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with PHP than implement it in PHP. Since GCM uses only 2 GETs with HTTPS, you can easily implement it in any language, even batch processing with curl (i am using this for testing). You can find the calls [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7639678/c2dm-401-error-when-sending-messages-after-receiving-id-and-auth-token/7771710#7771710).

Note that you need a curl.exe which is capable of doing HTTPS. The link from Avio's answer shows you how to do that in PHP, stick to that and do not use C++.